# PowerShell replace variables with their values defined in the context, but don't touch unknown variables

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if there is a way to replace variables in PowerShell script block with their value that is defined in a scope. I also don't want to replace variables that are not available in the scope. My goal is to get a Script block that is "self contained" as much as possible.

```
$outerVariable = "hello"
$Command = {
    Write-Host "$outerVariable"
    $innerVariable = "world"

    Write-Host "$innerVariable"
}

$Command = [scriptblock]::Create($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($Command.ToString()))

$Command
```

It results in:

```
Write-Host "hello"
= "world"

Write-Host ""
```

But I want this:

```
Write-Host "hello"
$innerVariable = "world"

Write-Host "$innerVariable"
```

Comment: What's the end goal? If you just invoke your scriptblock: `& $Command` you would get the expected result.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I am using Posh-SSH to invoke a script remotely on a machine but it doesn't accept a `scriptblock`, it only accepts a string. But I want to get the impression of running the script block if possible so I can use variables defined outside of script block.

Comment: If you want to invoke the scriptblock remotely then `$outerVariable` wouldn't be seen in the remote scope so you need to clarify this

Comment: That is why I use `InvokeCommand.ExpandString` to make it non-existent by replacing it with its value

Comment: there isn't a fail proof method to do this. you might be able to extract the variable expressions thru the AST and replace them with the corresponding values but that will break pretty easily, i.e. as soon as you try to inject an array or any complex object